# Failed to fetch jessie backports repository

Tags: debian, repository

I'm using a docker image as a base for my own development that adds the jessie backports repository in its Dockerfile and uses that to install a dependency. This image uses the following command to add the repository:

```
echo "deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

The problem is that fetching packages from the backports repository now  fails with the following error (this used to work previously):

```
W: Failed to fetch
http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch
http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages
 404  Not Found
```

I looked on that server, and those paths are indeed not present there.

I tried to figure out on the Debian backports site whether this particular repository should still be available, and I didn't find any indication that this was deprecated or something like that.

Is this a temporary issue with the repository, or is the jessie-backports repository not available anymore? And if this is not a temporary issue, what options do I have to use this or an equivalent repository without upgrading to the newer Debian stable version?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/how-to-work-around-release-file-expired-problem-on-a-local-mirror

Comment: This is essentially the same question as [apt-get update is failing in debian](https://superuser.com/q/1417617/53590) on [su].

Comment: I am unable to add answer here. For me I had to change "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list" file. Change the line "deb http://cloudfront.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main" to "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main"

Answer (score 252, accepted):

[Wheezy and Jessie were recently removed from the mirror network](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2019/03/msg00006.html), so if you want to continue fetching Jessie backports, you need to use `archive.debian.org` instead:

```
deb [check-valid-until=no] http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

(Validity checks need to be disabled since the repository is no longer being updated. Jessie’s `apt` doesn’t support the `check-valid-until` flag, see [inostia’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/508840/86440) for details, and the configuration summary further down in this answer.)

The `jessie-updates` repository has been removed: all the updates have been merged with the main repository, and there will be no further non-security updates. So any references to `jessie-updates` in `sources.list` or `sources.list.d` files need to be removed. Security updates [will continue to be provided](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using#Using_Debian_Long_Term_Support_.28LTS.29), on LTS-supported architectures, in the security repository, until June 30, 2020.

Since you’re building a container image, I *highly* recommend basing it on Debian 9 (Stretch) instead. To stay on Debian 8 (Jessie), your repositories should end up looking like

```
deb http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

(without the `jessie-updates` repository).

You’ll also need to disable validity checks in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` (which will apply to all repositories):

```
Acquire::Check-Valid-Until "false";
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Upgrading Debian is certainly something I will do in the future, it's just not as simple as my dependency has another dependency that is the actual base image that determines the Debian version. Upgrading that needs a a bit more testing.

Comment: Oh I understand it’s not straightforward ;-). I felt it would be dishonest of me not to recommend it though (despite your mention in your question that it wasn’t an option).

Comment: I am still getting error even after updating /etc/apt/sources.list as following :

root@2664d9755cee:/# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main

Comment: Got these errors:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/dists/jessie/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: Sorry, my answer was perhaps not all that clear; the line I gave was only for backports. `jessie-updates` doesn’t exist any more, so you should delete that altogether, and the Jessie security updates are still on `security.debian.org`.

Comment: Why are updates and backports now archived for LTS architectures of jessie such as amd64? They claim to still offer support until June 2020. Archiving those repos means they won't be publishing new security patches! The announcement linked says 'for all non-LTS architectures,' and this clearly seems incorrect.

Comment: @Ian no, security updates are provided on `security.debian.org`, not through backports or updates. There won’t be any more non-LTS stable updates, so `jessie-updates` is no longer useful on the main mirror network, and there won’t be any more backports either, so the same goes for `jessie-backports`.

Comment: Not working for me:

```
E: Release file for http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/InRelease is expired (invalid since 34d 20h 7min 12s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

Comment: @Avi indeed, thanks, see the updated answer (which works fine for me).

Comment: Have found that subsequent `apt` commands also seem to require `-o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false` (per https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45973/186565) in order to avoid the expiration error.

Comment: @sumitsu thanks, setting that in `apt.conf` should work too (see my update).

Comment: @StephenKitt thanks for this we were having a hard time finding out why the packages seemed to have disappeared. I think such a move would warrant a notice to a slightly larger audience than debian-devel-announce (such as https://www.debian.org/News/)

Comment: Thank you so much @StephenKitt. It worked fine using this way:

`# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main`

Comment: @Rafael didn’t it work with `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie main` instead of `http://archive.debian.org/debian`? The repository is still there, it should work fine from the main mirrors...

Comment: Hi @StephenKitt, sorry by my late reply on this. Actually it worked with both.

Comment: The solution is does not work for now:

`E: Release file for http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/InRelease is expired (invalid since 51d 14h 37min 55s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.`

Comment: @Atombit you need to read the answer all the way to the end: you’re missing `Acquire::Check-Valid-Until "false";`.

Comment: "without the jessie-updates repository, and you’ll need to disable validity checks" makes it seem like you don't need to disable the validity check if you leave `jessie-updates` in the list of sources

Comment: Thanks @Tim, I’ve split things up to make that part clearer.

Comment: More on it [here](https://www.lucas-nussbaum.net/blog/?p=947).

Comment: I ran into this problem, updated the `sources.list` but it was still using the `ftp.(...)` url. After pulling a couple hairs out, I figured out there was a `backports.list` in the `sources.list.d` directory, which defined the `ftp.`-version. Just check if that file is there, and edit it there, or remove it and add the backports url to the `sources.list` file. Just leaving this here in case somebody else runs into this issue and isn't that familiar with the system yet.

Answer (score 55):

After trying solutions suggested by @inostia and @Stephen Kitt I was still getting the following error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I figured out that it can be solved by removing the line `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main` from `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

I ended up with the following snippet in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "deb [check-valid-until=no] http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie.list
RUN echo "deb [check-valid-until=no] http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
RUN sed -i '/deb http:\/\/deb.debian.org\/debian jessie-updates main/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```

Comment: I had to teak sed part as In my case docker image (postgres) was using httpredir.debian.org  instead of deb.debian.org.

Comment: Here is an updated version of your `sed` command that did the trick for me: `sed -i '/deb http:\/\/\(deb\|httpredir\).debian.org\/debian jessie.* main/d' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Is there any no-spike solution? If repository is deprecated what is the new repository where to get necessary extensions?

Comment: here is the final wersion which works for me: RUN echo "deb [check-valid-until=no] http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie.list
RUN echo "deb [check-valid-until=no] http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
RUN sed -i '/deb http:\/\/\(deb\|httpredir\).debian.org\/debian jessie.* main/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
RUN echo 'Acquire::Check-Valid-Until "false";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf

Comment: this worked for me and any subsequent apt-get update should have the -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false option. In my case i was installing couchbase using RUN dpkg -i couchbase-release-1.0-4-amd64.deb and then 
RUN apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update && \
    apt-get -y install libcouchbase-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

Answer (score 5):

For those using NodeJS with older docker image foundations. I had some frozen images that had these older sources for the compilation of extra libs.

Context: if you wanted to install python during a docker build you ran into this issue during a build of the image (within the last 24 hours) as it failed to source dependencies during a docker build.

I tried the archive path recommendations in this post but couldn't get past the 404's. (also coming from the archive.debian.org location as of today)

Solution: I ended up switching to the latest container version of node (which has python libs already pre-installed) that, and updating some libs in the package json (which now also include binary libs that used to want pythyon) made the issue obsolete.

In the end, updating the foundation image for the container stack (node:latest) seemed to be the most straight-forward path to resolution.

Be wary of stale image stacks with binary dependencies included, they'll probably take a while to update the core OS layer.

Comment: Hi Glen, thanks for posting. I think I'm running into same issue in dockerfile as I have "RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install supervisor python python-dev curl -y --force-yes". I'm using FROM node:6.11.2, what must I do to get past this?

Comment: For Docker Node images, an  alternative is to use the `-stretch` images: `node:<version>-stretch`

Answer (score 2):

```
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list << EOF
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main

deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
EOF

apt-get update
apt-get install -y --force-yes xxx
```

works for me

Answer (score 1):

If nothing works anymore, with a panel of those errors:

```
Unable to correct missing packages.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
W: GPG error
W: An error occurred during the signature verification.
Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Failed to fetch
E: Aborting install
```

Consider a **full distribution upgrade** and a source list clean up to save your machine. It will takes only minutes with those notes, but it's worst it.

First visit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, and remove everything. (**Do backups**).

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`, leave only this line:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib
```

Then, as root, run:

```
aptitude update
aptitude full-upgrade
```

Confirm the various messages. Then try:

```
sudo apt update
```

Should raise no errors, just confirming:

```
Reading package lists... Done
```

Some various packages can raise some **conflicts**, on those cases, to be used one time, this will resolve the various conflicts:

```
sudo aptitude -y install packagename otherpackagename
```

**Possible other error:**

```
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
*648ACFXXXXX2FAB138*
```

To solve, import the public keys as specified:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 648ACFXXXXX2FAB138
```

**You might hit a very rare message!**

```
A reboot is required to replace the running dbus-daemon.
Please reboot the system when convenient.
```

**You might hit an issue with olds kernels and libc:**

```
Kernel must be upgraded

This version of the GNU libc requires kernel version 3.2 or later.  Please upgrade your kernel
```

---

Do not apply those notes for public servers. Always go for the last LTS.

---

https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-uptodate.en.html

https://askubuntu.com/questions/364404/e-unable-to-fetch-some-archives-maybe-run-apt-get-update-or-try-with-fix-mis

https://askubuntu.com/questions/766883/there-is-no-public-key-available-for-the-following-key-ids-1397bc53640db551