# Dockerfile - debian Jessie 404: packages not found

Tags: debian, docker

I'm trying to set up a docker container on Debian 9.8, but I keep getting the following error when I run `docker-compose up -d`:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Which then causes the process to be cut short.

I have the following Dockerfile (shortened for readability) with 2 calls to `apt-get update` that I have modified with suggestions [from](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508724/failed-to-fetch-jessie-backports-repository) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361762/apt-get-update-fails-with-404-in-a-previously-working-build) [pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387506/how-to-fix-failed-to-fetch-debian-jessie-updates-issue-on-docker) to no avail:

```
FROM python:3.5.2
RUN echo "deb [check-valid-until=no] http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie.list
RUN sed -i '/deb http:\/\/deb.debian.org\/debian jessie-updates main/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
RUN sed -i '/jessie-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y git 
[...]
RUN apt-get install -y xvfb
RUN pip install algoliasearch==1.12.0
[...]
RUN pip install gunicorn

RUN echo "deb [check-valid-until=no] http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie.list
RUN sed -i '/deb http:\/\/deb.debian.org\/debian jessie-updates main/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
RUN sed -i '/jessie-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update

RUN wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
[...]
RUN export PATH="$(pwd)":$PATH
WORKDIR /usr/src/api
CMD sh -c "gunicorn sourcingplatform.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:80"
```

I also removed any references I could find to jessie in `/etc/apt/sources/list`. What am I missing?

Comment: For reference, multi-post is at https://stackoverflow.com/q/55513442/2344631

Comment: Hi Jessica. Cross-posted questions are closed on this site. It might make sense delete the [so] version (I see it's actually been nominated for closure as *Off Topic*) – even though it already has a helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the first line here doesn’t match, so you’re still trying to fetch `jessie-updates`:

```
RUN sed -i '/deb http:\/\/deb.debian.org\/debian jessie-updates main/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```

Use the more general `sed` command you already have:

```
RUN sed -i '/jessie-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```