# jessie-backports fix creates "has no installation candidate" error

Tags: debian

I was recently affected [by the jessie-backports issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508724/failed-to-fetch-jessie-backports-repository) and have attempted to fix it as follows.

```
  - run:
      name: Apply jessie-backports Fix
      command: |
        rm /etc/apt/sources.list
        echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
        echo "deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
        echo "Acquire::Check-Valid-Until false;" | tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10-nocheckvalid
        echo 'Package: *\nPin: origin "archive.debian.org"\nPin-Priority: 500' | tee -a /etc/apt/preferences.d/10-archive-pin
        apt-get update
  - run: 
      name: Install Dependencies
      command: |
        npm install -g @angular/cli
        npm install
        npm install -g firebase-tools
        apt-get -y -qq update
        apt-get -y -qq install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
        if [[ "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" == "master" ]]; then
          apt-get -y -qq update
          apt-get -y -qq install python3.4-dev
          curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
          python3.4 get-pip.py --user
          echo 'export PATH=/root/.local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile 
          source ~/.bash_profile
          pip install awscli --upgrade --user
        fi
```

However, whenever I run my build, it fails with the following errors:

```
E: Package 'gconf-service' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libasound2' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libatk1.0-0' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libdbus-1-3' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libgconf-2-4' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libgtk-3-0' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libnspr4' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libx11-xcb1' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libxcomposite1' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libxcursor1' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libxdamage1' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libxfixes3' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libxi6' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libxrandr2' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libxss1' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libxtst6' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'fonts-liberation' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libappindicator1' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libnss3' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'lsb-release' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'xdg-utils' has no installation candidate
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is your first code block your attempt to fix the issue? The post you link to provides an answer by user Stephen Kitt. Have you tried what he has outlined in his answer?