# How to install debian jessie-backports package after package removal using Docker?

Tags: debian, docker

**The problem**

I'm trying to use jessie-backports in a docker repository for a Ruby on Rails project using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.4.1
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN true

RUN echo 'alias ll="ls --color=auto -l"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN apt-get remove -y python
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

RUN echo "deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y certbot -t jessie-backports
```

However when I attempted to build the docker image. the following error popped up in the middle of the installation:

```
E: Release file for http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/InRelease is expired (invalid since 77d 3h 49min 17s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

As of March 27 **Lucas Nussbaum** wrote in this [blogpost](https://www.lucas-nussbaum.net/blog/?p=947) that jessie-updates and jessie-backports were going to be removed from Debian mirrors. 
The blog post I mentioned stated that what I needed to do was replace:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

With this other commands:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
echo 'Acquire::Check-Valid-Until no;' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99no-check-valid-until
```

So I changed the commands as follows:

```
FROM ruby:2.4.1
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN true

RUN echo 'alias ll="ls --color=auto -l"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN apt-get remove -y python
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo 'Acquire::Check-Valid-Until no;' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99no-check-valid-until
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y certbot -t jessie-backports
```

However the same issue is still present.

I also attempted to move the commands before any **apt** command like this:

```
FROM ruby:2.4.1
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN true

RUN echo 'alias ll="ls --color=auto -l"' >> ~/.bashrc

RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo 'Acquire::Check-Valid-Until no;' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99no-check-valid-until
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get remove -y python
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y certbot -t jessie-backports
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/508728/332764) from Stephen Kitt.

Comment: What error do you get with the last variant? It works for me, as-is (although I’d change the `jessie-backports` line to use `>>` instead of `>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue I needed to pull all of the Debian main repository, for certbot to be installed correctly.

```
FROM ruby:2.4.1
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN true

RUN echo 'alias ll="ls --color=auto -l"' >> ~/.bashrc

RUN echo "deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get remove -y python
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

# Let's Encrypt (SSL CERTIFICATES)
RUN echo "deb [check-valid-until=no] http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo 'Acquire::Check-Valid-Until no;' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99no-check-valid-until
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y certbot -t jessie-backports
```