# Debian 8 -bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory

Tags: debian, java

On a new Debian system I installed JRE using

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

Then I downloaded a jar-file and tried running it:

```
java -jar server.jar
```

The file threw an exception:

> java.lang.unsupportedclassversionerror unsupported major.minor version
>   52.0

So I started looking for a solution and followed a user's instruction:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/java
sudo ln -s /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java /usr/bin
```

Afterwards I realized that I don't even have a directory `/Library` and therefore this link isn't pointing anywhere.

Now I can't even run java anymore:

```
java -jar server.jar
-bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I already tried uninstalling JRE und reinstalling it:

```
apt-get remove default-jre
apt-get update
apt-get install default-jre
```

Which didn't change anything though.

Java seems to be installed:

```
    find /usr -name java
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To restore your `/usr/bin/java` link, you should run

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -a
```

If you were using Debian 9 (as mentioned initially), you shouldn’t have run into these issues, since OpenJDK 8 is the default there and OpenJDK 7 isn’t even available. To fix things so that you can run version 52 classes (*i.e.* Java 8 classes), install OpenJDK 8:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

On Debian 8 you can install OpenJDK 8 from backports:

```
echo deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
echo 'Acquire::Check-Valid-Until "false";' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf
sudo apt update
sudo apt -t jessie-backports install openjdk-8-jre
```

(See [Failed to fetch jessie backports repository](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/508724/86440) for details.)

You’ll then need to specifically choose OpenJDK 8 as the default:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

(To see the possible values, run `/usr/sbin/update-java-alternatives -l`.)

Answer (score 1):

If you get error as below:

```
bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Run:

```
apt-get install libc6-i386
```

Some 32bit libs are missing

Comment: No, `/usr/bin/java` is a symbolic link that is broken, according to the question.  Installing some 32-bit libraries will not make the link into the non-existing directory `/Library` work.