# How to install libdrm2-dev on Debian jessie-backports

Tags: debian, backports

I am using Debian 8 jessie-backports, how can I install the package `libdrm2-dev`? I tried `apt install libdrm2-dev/jessie-backports` but I get:

`E: Unable to locate package libdrm2-dev`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `libdrm-dev` instead:

```
sudo apt install libdrm-dev/jessie-backports
```

I’m assuming you have updated your repository configuration for Jessie backports; see [Failed to fetch jessie backports repository](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/508724/86440) for details.